# Is it possible to use os.walk over SSH?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh

I'm new to Python so forgive me if this is basic, I've searched but can't find an answer. I'm trying to convert a Perl script into Python (3.x) which connects to a remote server and copies the files in a given directory to the local machine. Integrity of the transfer is paramount and there are several steps built-in to ensure a complete and accurate transfer.

The first step is to get a complete listing of the files to be passed to rsync. The Perl script has the following lines to accomplish this:

```
@dir_list = `ssh user@host 'find $remote_dir -type f -exec /bin/dirname {} \\;'`;
@file_list = `ssh user@host 'find $remote_dir -type f -exec /bin/basename {} \\;'`;
```

The two lists are then `join`ed to create $full_list.

Rather than  open two separate `ssh` instances I'd like to open one and use `os.walk` to get the information using:

```
for remdirname, remdirnames, remfilesnames in os.walk(remotedir):
    for remfilename in remfilesnames:
        remfulllist.append(os.path.join(remdirname, remfilename))
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Unless `remotedir` is mounted somewhere, `os.walk` has no way of reaching it.

Comment: Do you mean `-type d` for the `@dirlist` line?  And I think as @Bryan notes below, you can compute the dir_list and file_list based on invoking ssh from python.

Comment: if you do not need arbitrary logic (i.e. real python code) to process the list of files to copy once you got it, then you would be much more simple and robust by just using plain rsync and includes/excludes/filters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, os.walk can't be used in this way.

Comment: sounds pretty definitive, thank you. Now I just have to find the best conversion of the `ssh` command line.

Comment: @LeoB: unless I'm missing something, you can get by with a single ssh command to get the full path to each file (ie: find $remote_dir -type f). Then, iterate over that result and for each full path compute the dirname and filename.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a usable walk-function. Currently not tested by me.
https://pysftp.readthedocs.org/en/release_0.2.8/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.walktree